# socket.io: How to emit an Array and a Variable simultaneously

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

Learning Node.js, Express.js and Socket.io.

Made a Chat an it works so far.

Now I would like to emit to the Client, that a user has entered or left the chat by emiting a variable that indicates that...

Ist that possible?

So something like this:

Server.js

```
var users = [];
var inout;
function updateUsers(){
    io.emit('users', users, 'inout', inout);
}
```

Client:

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':3000' );
    socket.on('users', function(data){

// how to get the 'inout' here? }
```

Thanks for any Help... ;)

Comment: You ;) don't ;) need ;) all ;) those ;) winky ;) faces ;). (*ps, [**this**](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) might be of help.*)

Comment: Oh no! Where did all my smilies go? ;O
I like to show my emotions.. hehe ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to emit object:

```
let users = []
let inout

function updateUsers() {
    io.emit('users', {users, inout});
}
```

Comment: Arghh... so simple... Thanks... and for all noob proggers like me: on client side you then obviously have to separate these two objects in "data.users" and "data.inout"... thank you very much, Pasha :)

Comment: You're welcome. On the client you can destructure data object `socket.on('users', ({users, inout}) => { /* ... */ })`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read the [documentation](http://socket.io/docs/) more clearly, because this doesn't look like Socket.io.

Here's an example of sending an array, along with some other data:

```
var io = require("socket.io")(3001);
io.emit("myEvent", {
  somethingToSendToBrowser: "Hello",
  arrayToSendToBrowser: [
    "I'm the data that will get sent.",
    "I'm some more data.",
    "Here's the third piece of data."
  ]
});
```

---

```
<script src="/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io("http://localhost:3001");
socket.on("myEvent", function(data){
  console.log(data.arrayToSendToBrowser);
  // ["I'm the data that will get sent.", "I'm some more data.", "Here's the third piece of data.]"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Robert, seems to be the same working solution as Pasha proposed.. :)